# Read all posts on hamburger menu/overlay

Tags: html, css

I have been staring at this for hours, and moving things around in countless combinations. I have read everything on visibility and what properties make things disappear but still cause flow around, and what actually "collapsible" means, and I still cannot work this out.

I watched an introductory tutorial on HTML and CSS and decided to try coding it myself. Everything is visually fine and does what it's supposed to do.

The hamburger itself makes sense using the `before` and `after` for the visuals with a `checkbox` over it (with no `opacity` because that lets you respond to events). I conceptually understand everything quite well.

**My question is:**

After building out the overlay, even when the overlay menu is minimized (`checkbox` is `unchecked`), I cannot click on the button (link a tag) because the `.menu` is still overlaying the whole `viewport` even when my `checkbox` is toggled.

I did everything as the instructor did. I even went through his code as I am convinced that his code does not work either.

I read all about the properties, and thought that just setting the `div` visibility to `hidden` should work, but it does not.

I guess `visibility: hidden` does not actually collapse the element. But neither does `visibility:collapse`.

Only `display: none` does (but not on the `.menu`, but on the child `div .menu > .menu-shrink`), but since there is no midpoint, it cannot be used in a smooth transition, with the scale transition on the `checkbox`.

I tried to `transform: scale(0)`, yet after all this, the inspector shows that there is still a `.menu` overlay across the whole overlay.

I learned that the transform actually keeps the original space and does not create overflow. But still, nothing under its original state can be clicked.

When a child `div` has a defined `height` and `width`, it stretches the parent `div`, correct? But if you set that `div`'s `visibility` to `hidden`, wouldn't it show that.

I tried to set `display: none;` on `.menu`, but still nothing.

The error is either on `.menu` or `.menu .menu shrink`.

```css
:root {
  --primary-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  --secondary-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  --overlay-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  --menu-speed: .7s;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

/* Showcase-Header */

.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 3rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
}

#showcase {
  position: relative;
  background: var(--primary-color);
  color: white;
  height: 100vh;
}

#showcase::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: url(./img/pexels-darius-krause-2228152.jpeg) no-repeat center
    center/cover;
  z-index: -1;
}

#showcase .showcase-content {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

#showcase h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  padding: 0.75rem 1.5rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  background-color: var(--secondary-color);
   backdrop-filter: saturate(190%) blur(3px);
  transition: all 0.2s;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px;
}

/* Hamburger Menu (Mobile) */

.menu-wrap {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu-wrap .toggler {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;

  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.menu-wrap .hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  padding: 1rem;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* hambuerger menu lines */

.menu-wrap .hamburger > div {
  position: relative;
  flex: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: white;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

/* Hanburder lines Top and Bottom */

.menu-wrap .hamburger > div::before,
.menu-wrap .hamburger > div::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background: inherit;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu-wrap .hamburger > div::after {
  top: 10px;
}

/* Toggler Animation */

.menu-wrap .toggler:checked + .hamburger > div {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

/* Turns lines into X */

.menu-wrap .toggler:checked + .hamburger > div::before,
.menu-wrap .toggler:checked + .hamburger > div:after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

/* Rotate on hover when checked */

.menu-wrap .toggler:checked:hover + .hamburger > div {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}

/* When Hamburger Menu is Checked */

.menu-wrap .toggler:checked ~ .menu {
  visibility: visible;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

.menu-wrap .toggler:checked ~ .menu > .menu-shrink {
  transform: scale(1);
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  display: flex;
}

.menu-wrap .toggler:checked ~ .menu > .menu-shrink > .menu-fade {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 3s 0.3s;
}

.menu-wrap .toggler:checked ~ .menu > .menu-shrink > .menu-fade > 

/* Menu */

.menu-wrap .menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;  
  visibility: collapse;
}

.menu-wrap .menu > .menu-shrink {
  background-color: var(--overlay-color);
  backdrop-filter: saturate(190%) blur(3px);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  /* flex: none; */
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transform: scale(0);

  
  transition: all var(--menu-speed);
}

.menu-wrap .menu > .menu-shrink > .menu-fade {
  text-align: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 88vw;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.menu-wrap .menu > .menu-shrink > .menu-fade > ul {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10% 0;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 5%;
}

.menu-wrap .menu > .menu-shrink > .menu-fade > ul > li {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  opacity: 0.85;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

/* Menu Effects Once Open */

.hover-grow {
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.hover-grow:hover {
  transform: scale(2);
  opacity: 1;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="menu.css" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <title>Hamburger Menu Overlay</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="menu-wrap">
      <input type="checkbox" class="toggler" />
      <div class="hamburger"><div></div></div>
      <div class="menu">
        <div class="menu-shrink">
          <div class="menu-fade">
            <ul>
              <li class="hover-grow"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li class="hover-grow"><a href="#">About</a></li>
              <li class="hover-grow"><a href="#">Info</a></li>
              <li class="hover-grow"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
              <li class="hover-grow"><a href="#">Essay</a></li>
              <li class="hover-grow"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <header id="showcase">
      <div class="container showcase-content">
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur
          at accusamus repellat repellendus nihil quidem totam sapiente omnis
          quae. Facere.
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="btn">Read More</a>
      </div>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the checkbox in root and/or set `.menu` size to 0 if not checked.

```css
:root {
  --primary-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  --secondary-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  --overlay-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  --menu-speed: .7s;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

/* Showcase-Header */

.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 3rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
}

#showcase {
  position: relative;
  background: var(--primary-color);
  color: white;
  height: 100vh;
}

#showcase::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: url(./img/pexels-darius-krause-2228152.jpeg) no-repeat center
    center/cover;
  z-index: -1;
}

#showcase .showcase-content {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

#showcase h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  padding: 0.75rem 1.5rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  background-color: var(--secondary-color);
   backdrop-filter: saturate(190%) blur(3px);
  transition: all 0.2s;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px;
}

/* Hamburger Menu (Mobile) */

.menu-wrap {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu-wrap .toggler {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;

  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.menu-wrap .hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  padding: 1rem;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* hambuerger menu lines */

.menu-wrap .hamburger > div {
  position: relative;
  flex: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: white;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

/* Hanburder lines Top and Bottom */

.menu-wrap .hamburger > div::before,
.menu-wrap .hamburger > div::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background: inherit;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu-wrap .hamburger > div::after {
  top: 10px;
}

/* Toggler Animation */

.menu-wrap .toggler:checked + .hamburger > div {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

/* Turns lines into X */

.menu-wrap .toggler:checked + .hamburger > div::before,
.menu-wrap .toggler:checked + .hamburger > div:after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

/* Rotate on hover when checked */

#toggler:checked + .menu-wrap .toggler:hover + .hamburger > div {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}

/* When Hamburger Menu is Checked */

#toggler:checked + .menu-wrap .toggler ~ .menu {
  visibility: visible;
  transition-duration: all 0.2s;
}

#toggler:checked + .menu-wrap .toggler ~ .menu > .menu-shrink {
  transform: scale(1);
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  display: flex;
}

#toggler:checked + .menu-wrap .toggler ~ .menu > .menu-shrink > .menu-fade {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 3s 0.3s;
}

#toggler:checked + .menu-wrap .toggler ~ .menu > .menu-shrink > .menu-fade > 

/* Menu */

.menu-wrap .menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;  
  visibility: collapse;
}

.menu-wrap .menu > .menu-shrink {
  background-color: var(--overlay-color);
  backdrop-filter: saturate(190%) blur(3px);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  /* flex: none; */
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transform: scale(0);

  
  transition: all var(--menu-speed);
}

.menu-wrap .menu > .menu-shrink > .menu-fade {
  text-align: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 88vw;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.menu-wrap .menu > .menu-shrink > .menu-fade > ul {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10% 0;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 5%;
}

.menu-wrap .menu > .menu-shrink > .menu-fade > ul > li {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  opacity: 0.85;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

/* Menu Effects Once Open */

.hover-grow {
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.hover-grow:hover {
  transform: scale(2);
  opacity: 1;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}
#toggler:not(:checked) + .menu-wrap .menu {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="menu.css" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <title>Hamburger Menu Overlay</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggler" class="hide" />
    <div class="menu-wrap">
      <label class="toggler" for="toggler"></label>
      <div class="hamburger"><div></div></div>
      <div class="menu">
        <div class="menu-shrink">
          <div class="menu-fade">
            <ul>
              <li class="hover-grow"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li class="hover-grow"><a href="#">About</a></li>
              <li class="hover-grow"><a href="#">Info</a></li>
              <li class="hover-grow"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
              <li class="hover-grow"><a href="#">Essay</a></li>
              <li class="hover-grow"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <header id="showcase">
      <div class="container showcase-content">
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur
          at accusamus repellat repellendus nihil quidem totam sapiente omnis
          quae. Facere.
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="btn">Read More</a>
      </div>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm using the transform: scale() but that doesn't seem to be collapsable, so I still can't click the .btn under it. How else can I change the size? with a "size: 0; ?

Comment: use `width: 0` and `height: 0`